# C++ WinRT - GameControllerSwitchPosition() is for which part of gamepad?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, windows-runtime, position, center

I am using RawGameController API and from article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input.gamecontrollerswitchposition

Which part of Xbox controller shows the GameControllerSwitchPosition ?

I have tested Xbox controller, retrieved current button, axis states except the SwitchPosition where the API GameControllerSwitchPosition() always result in  **GameControllerSwitchPosition::Center**.

Any game controller or gamepad that has this "SwitchPosition" features ?

Any info or links to show the "Switch" mechanism as picture is greatly appreciated.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed **GameControllerSwitchPosition()** is actually referring to "**Point of View Hat**" under the controller panel properties such as picture below:

[**GameControllerSwitchPosition()** as **Point of View Hat** detection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfVop.jpg)

The above is true for PS4 DualShock 4 and some clone controller.

However, it is not the case for Xbox One controller where the view hat value positions are reported as part of Button section.

Hopes, this help.